# javac isn't recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, javac

I know this question has been asked a lot of times, but I tried a lot of solutions and none of them work. If I write "path" in prompt, I get this:

```
PATH=%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\W
indows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\P
rogram Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static; ;C:\Program Files\Commo
n Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
```

So, it seems correct.
What should I do?

Comment: are you sure your java is in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

Comment: Are you sure the extra spaces at the start are ignored?

Comment: I think this will help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Good call @PeterLawrey. I would advise the same since everything looks fine. Also just to add, I would advise surrounding each path entry in a pair of inverted commas to make sure that spaces dont cause any issue

Comment: @ Satheesh Cheveri: Yes, I'm sure. I just checked it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra space in front of `C:\...` Remove that.

```
...; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
    ^
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thats it. Also there is an unfilled space between two semicomma `Core-Static; ;C:\Program`

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
```

extra space before this line.

Answer (score 0):

in Windows environment you can set path in two ways

1) Temporary set path

open cmd(command prompt) start ---> run --- type cmd ----hit enter
in the cmd type this

set path  hit enter
Ex: set path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin

this will set path to current cmd window only

2) Permanently set path

right click my computer----- > properties -----> Advance ----> Environment variables ---->inside system variable Group box select path click edit,in opend window variable value text box put ; at the last and past the path of your jdk directory's bin   -----> select ok

now open the cmd type path command  see... that path in the out put text